# How to hide Android Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I have two EditText Views and a Button in Linearlayout. After Completion of writing in the edittext, I want to hide the Android Virtual keyboard, How can I do that?

Comment: its better to close rather than downvote right??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use the InputMethodManager class like this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( yourEditText.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
```