# Else condition is not being called

Tags: android, if-statement

I have an if condition which checks if the edittext is empty or not,if it is empty an alert is raised. But when I enter some values to the edittext then also it is giving me the alert

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calci extends Activity {
    TextView t1;
    EditText e1, e2;
    Button add, sub, mul, div;
    Context c=this;

    String b, a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calci);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        a = e1.getText().toString();
        b = e2.getText().toString();
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (a.equals("") || b.equals("")){

            AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
                // Setting Dialog Title
                a1.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                // Setting Dialog Message
                a1.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOMETHING");
                a1.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int button1) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                            });

                // Showing Alert Message
                AlertDialog alertDialog = a1.create();
                a1.show();

            } else {
            Log.d("sadasd", "msg");
            int result = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
//          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
//                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(add.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

    }

});
    }
}
```

I have an if condition which checks if the edittext is empty or not,if it is empty an alert is raised.But when I enter some values to the edittext then also it is giving me the alert.

Comment: you need to type something in both e1 and e2

Comment: Add breakpoints and debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way, by doing it in `onCreate()` method. You should do it in `onClick()` method like below,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    a = e1.getText().toString();
    b = e2.getText().toString();
    if (a.equals("") || b.equals(""))
    {
```

The actual reason is that in OnCreate() method EditText is blank as you have just initilize it. What you need is to insert a text init and then check for the condition. hence you need to write `a = e1.getText().toString();` & `b = e2.getText().toString();` statement in onClicck() method

Comment: it would be nice to explain what he should do/not do inside onCreate

Comment: @blackbelt sorry I was writting the answer.

Comment: ok i got it.
one more thing, i also want to hide the keyboard when the add button is clicked

Comment: Please check my answer [to hide the keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404412/3330969)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Get the `EditText` text inside the `ClickListener`

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        a = e1.getText().toString();
        b = e2.getText().toString();
        if (a.equals("") || b.equals("")){
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be inside on click listner to get updated value  before the button was pressed :

```
 a = e1.getText().toString();
 b = e2.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if (a.equals("") || b.equals(""))` will **not** be passing only when both `a` and `b` will have some values inside. So simply both `editTexts` should be filled in and you should check it also on the top of onClick listener because at that moment you simply do it only when your activity starts. So you have old values in `a and b` variables.

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   a = e1.getText().toString();
   b = e2.getText().toString();
```